# JavaScript Center Align

Tags: javascript, center, alignment

How can I align the entire script to center? I've never actually coded before in javascript and I just want to modify a quick bookmarklet. I've tried stuff like align=center for different components of the script but no luck. Is there something like `<center>` (in html) for js?

Thanks

EDIT: basically i want this to be centered on a page

```
function dEmbed(){
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com';
    iframe.style.width = w+'px';
    iframe.style.height= h+'px';
    iframe.style.border= "0";
    iframe.style.margin= "0";
    iframe.setAttribute("scrolling","no");
    iframe.setAttribute("id","NAME");
    document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Please give us more details - your terminology is all mixed up and it's hard to understand what you are looking to do. (Especially please don't use the word script the way you do.)

Comment: Check my edited answer below, I solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by injecting the iframe into an existing div with `text-align: center`.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/PYX5s/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can't centre a script, it doesn't look like anything so there is nothing to centre.

If the script generates some HTML, then you can to centre the generated elements. This should be done using [the usual CSS techniques](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/) applied to the generated element.

(`<center>` and the `align` attribute were [deprecated in 1998](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/) and shouldn't be used).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
iframe.style.margin= "0";
```

To:

```
iframe.style.margin= "auto";
```

If it doesn't work, let me know in a comment.

OK, try this change instead, change:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
```

to:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = w+'px';
div.style.margin= "auto";
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
```

And change:

```
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```

To:

```
div.appendChild(iframe);
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

Comment: I worked on this for like two hours last night, I can't get it to center

Comment: Are you setting w and h someplace? (Width and height?) I assumed you were since it works but not centered? I just tried my code and it works fine, as long as you set those variables.